# NavigationDrawer with ExpandableListView app crash when select item in Android 2.3

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-2.3-gingerbread, expandablelistadapter

I have a NavigationDrawer with ExpandableListView where only some items have subitems. In addition the first item of list have a different layout that the other group items of ExpandableListView, the layout only have an imageview. The app works fine in all devices but in devices with android 2.3 the app crash. This is the adapter for ExpandableListView:

```
public class NavDrawerAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<NavDrawerItem> _listDataHeader; // header titles
private HashMap<String, List<NavMenuSection>> _listDataChild;

private static class NavMenuItemHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
    private ImageView iconView;
}

private class NavMenuSectionHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
}

private class NavMenuHeaderHolder {
    private ImageView imgView;
}

public NavDrawerAdapter(Context context,
        List<NavDrawerItem> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<NavMenuSection>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(
            this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getLabel()).get(
            childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition,
        final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    NavMenuSection child = (NavMenuSection) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_section,
                null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.navmenusection_label);

    txtListChild.setText(child.getLabel());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    if (this._listDataChild.get(
            this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getLabel())!= null)
        return this._listDataChild.get(
                this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getLabel()).size();
    else 
        return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    NavDrawerItem menuItem = this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);

    if ( menuItem.getType() == NavMenuItem.ITEM_TYPE ) {
        convertView = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem );
    } else if (menuItem.getType() == NavMenuHeader.HEADER_TYPE){
        convertView = getHeaderView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    } 

    return convertView;
}

public View getItemView( View convertView, ViewGroup parentView, NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem ) {

    NavMenuItem menuItem = (NavMenuItem) navDrawerItem ;
    NavMenuItemHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.drawer_list_item, parentView, false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById( R.id.navmenuitem_label );
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById( R.id.navmenuitem_icon );

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuItemHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView ;
        navMenuItemHolder.iconView = iconView ;

        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if ( navMenuItemHolder == null ) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuItem.getLabel());
    navMenuItemHolder.iconView.setImageResource(menuItem.getIcon());

    return convertView ;
}

public View getHeaderView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

    NavMenuHeader menuHeader = (NavMenuHeader) navDrawerItem ;
    NavMenuHeaderHolder navMenuHeaderHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.navdrawer_header, parentView, false);
        ImageView labelView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById( R.id.img_header);

        navMenuHeaderHolder = new NavMenuHeaderHolder();
        navMenuHeaderHolder.imgView = labelView ;
        convertView.setTag(navMenuHeaderHolder);
    } else {
        navMenuHeaderHolder = (NavMenuHeaderHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    int nIdDrawable = _context.getResources().getIdentifier(menuHeader.getLabel(), "drawable", _context.getPackageName());

    navMenuHeaderHolder.imgView.setImageResource(nIdDrawable);

    return convertView ;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition,
        int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

And here is the part of activity with the definition of ExpandableListView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_primera));

    navConf = getNavDrawerConfiguration();

    navDrawer = (ScrimInsetsFrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrimInsetsFrameLayout);


    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListViewDrawer); 

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    expListView.setAdapter(navConf.getBaseAdapter());
    expListView.setGroupIndicator(null); 

 // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {

            //Si no es itinerarios
            if (groupPosition != 9 && groupPosition != 0)
                selectItem(groupPosition, 0);

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            //Si no es itinerarios
            int len = navConf.getBaseAdapter().getGroupCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (i != groupPosition) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(i);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {


        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectItem(groupPosition, childPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
.....
}
```

I have been debugging the app for Android 2.3 and the app start ok but when I click an item list, in the method getGroupView the convertview received is wrong for the first item list. The convertview received is the view for NavMenuItem not for NavMenuHeader, then the app crash. This issue doesn't happen with others devices with newer android version. What it could be the problem?

The error is the following:

```
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.flipaos.hermandadcarmendelashuertas.NavDrawerAdapter$NavMenuItemHolder
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at com.flipaos.hermandadcarmendelashuertas.NavDrawerAdapter.getHeaderView(NavDrawerAdapter.java:192)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at com.flipaos.hermandadcarmendelashuertas.NavDrawerAdapter.getGroupView(NavDrawerAdapter.java:120)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:445)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1414)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1290)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1576)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1265)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7200)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7200)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:911)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7200)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7200)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
04-16 15:07:58.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3532):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7200)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are saying app crash, then where is the LogCat trace?

Comment: I add the error in the question.